# How to validate google analytics tracking (events, page tracking) in android apps?

Tags: android, validation, google-analytics

Please help me in how i can validate/debug the google analytics tracking like custom events, page variables sent to Google analytics?

I used chrome web debugging but i was able to debug the web pages opened through chrome but not android application......

Comment: Please be more specific. What issue, exactly, are you having? Please edit your question to include as much information as possible about what you want/need help with.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use Google Analytics Measurement Protocol for sending hits to GA.

use debug in url `https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect`

Here is a doc related to validating hits in Measurement Protocol.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/validating-hits

Answer (score 0):

[Disclaimer: this is my product]
Normally you would use debuggers such as the ones in Chrome, Firefox or Safari, or proxies such as Charles.
Unfortunately this still requires you to sit in front of the PC to run tests.

For large websites, consider automating the testing process with solutions such as Hub'Scan http://www.hub-scan.com

There are other players such as Observepoint or Tag Inspector or Data True or Ghostery.